# Refactoring in model: what's going wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring, models

I'm currently trying to DRY up this initial verbose code:

```
def planting_dates_not_nil?
    !plant_out_week_min.blank? || !plant_out_week_max.blank? || !sow_out_week_min.blank? || !sow_out_week_max.blank?
  end

  def needs_planting?(week)
    if !plant_out_week_min.blank? && !plant_out_week_max.blank?
      (plant_out_week_min..plant_out_week_max).include? (week) 
    end
  end

  def needs_sowing?(week)
    if !sow_out_week_min.blank? && !sow_out_week_max.blank?
      (sow_out_week_min..sow_out_week_max).include? (week)
    end 
  end

  def needs_harvesting?(week)
    if !harvest_week_min.blank? && !harvest_week_max.blank?
      (harvest_week_min..harvest_week_max).include? (week) 
    end
  end
```

here's my intial attempt:

```
  def tasks_for_week(week,*task_names)
    task_names.each do |task_name|
      to_do_this_week = []
        unless read_attribute(task_name).nil?
          if (read_attribute("#{task_name}_week_min")..read_attribute("#{task_name}_week_max")).include? (week)
            to_do_this_week << task_name
          end
        end
      end
  end
```

However, when I run this code in the console as follows:

```
p.tasks_for_week(Date.today.cweek, :plant_out, :sow_out])
```

I get an unexpected result...even though the plant does not need to be planted out, I still get an array of both task names returned ( [:plant_out, :sow_out]

Can anyone let me know how I'd clean this up and have the tasksforweek method return the expected results?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is returning the result of `task_names.each`.  `each` always returns what it started with.  So you need to actually return your result.

Also, you are recreating you `to_do_this_week` array on every iteration of the loop, which would wipe it clean.

```
def tasks_for_week(week, *task_names)
  to_do_this_week = []
  task_names.each do |task_name|
    if some_condition
      to_do_this_week << task_name 
    end
  end
  to_do_this_week
end
```

Or this:

```
def tasks_for_week(week, *task_names)
  returning [] do |to_do_this_week|
    task_names.each do |task_name|
      if some_condition
        to_do_this_week << task_name 
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But I think this is probably your best best:

```
def tasks_for_week(week, *task_names)
  task_names.find_all do |task_name|
    some_condition
  end
end
```

That last one uses `find_all` which iterates over an array and will return a new array populated with any objects that the block return a true value for.

Lastly, your conditional logic is a bit crazy too.  You can use the `[]` accessors for active record fields in a dynamic way.  And it's usually clearer to use the positive case instead of the double negative of `unless something.nil?`.  And if this is a common use for creating a range, it might be best to farm that out to a method:

```
def week_range_for_task(task)
  self["#{task_name}_week_min"]..self["#{task_name}_week_max"]
end

...

self[task_name] && week_range_for_task(task_name).include?(week)
```

Making the whole method:

```
def tasks_for_week(week, *task_names)
  task_names.find_all do |task_name|
    self[task_name] && week_range_for_task(task_name).include?(week)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks again Squeegy for taking the time to refactor this so fully. Really helping me understand the basics.

I assume that I can use select in place of find_all.

Comment: Code above didn't quite work since self["task_name"] will always fail (needs to be task_name_weeks_min and task_name_weeks_max). I've included the amended code below. Can you see how to refactor any further?

Comment: well self[task_name] was supposed to mirror "unless read_attribute(task_name).nil?".  But it appears you have the right idea now.  Looks good.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note with the above is that `self[task_name]` seems to get the raw data from the database, ignoring any custom getter methods you may written.

If you want to use custom getters or if you have any methods you'd like to treat as attributes, you can use `self.send(task_name)` instead of `self[task_name]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the slightly amended code with a new condition method in there.

```
  def whole_range_exists?(method_name)
        self["#{method_name}_week_min"] && self["#{method_name}_week_max"]
      end

      def week_range_for_task(task_name)
        self["#{task_name}_week_min"]..self["#{task_name}_week_max"]
      end

      def tasks_for_week(week, *task_names)
        task_names.find_all do |task_name|
          whole_range_exists?(task_name) && week_range_for_task(task_name).include?(week)
        end
      end
```